# Interact with input fields like textfield text view and button action in webview using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am looking for some solution so i need to first know that is this possible that using objective c in Xcode can we interact in quite extensive and deep level, like adding some text in textfield and textview and change label colors and interact with button actions ?
I googled but not able to find my desired solution

Comment: No show some dialog and there will be next button on top navigation bar by tapping next button this will highlight each button and input field by their own order.

Comment: yes, go and learn the language and you'll see that it can do a to more, though that's because of Cocoa(Touch), not obj-c (or swift)

Comment: Which language you are referring here, objective c?

Comment: and any helping link?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Cocoa.html